# Strange issue with RequireJS and Fancybox

Tags: javascript, requirejs, fancybox-2

I'm cleaning up some old code at work and started by trying to get things to be a little more modular. I'm using RequireJS to load javascript libraries as I require (heh) them. Anyway, I'm having a periodic problem with fancybox, in that it intermittently fails to load (without showing a 404 or anything in the chrome debugger). Here's what I have in my app.js:

```

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "knockout": "knockout-3.4.0",
        "knockout.validation": "knockout.validation.min",
        "jquery": "jquery-1.8.2",
        "fancybox": "jquery.fancybox.pack",
        "pager": "Page/pager",
        "queryBuilder": "query-builder.min",
        "jQuery.extendext": "jQuery.extendext.min",
        "doT": "doT.min",
        "dataTables": "jquery.dataTables.min"
    },
    baseUrl: "/ucampaignmanager/Scripts",
    shim: {
        "jquery": {
            exports: "jQuery"
        },
        "jQuery.extendext": {
            depends: "jQuery",
            exports: "jQuery.extendext"
        },
        "knockout": {
            exports: "ko"
        },
        "knockout.validation": {
            depends: "ko"
        },
        "fancybox": {
            depends: "jQuery",
            exports: "jQuery.fn.fancybox"
        },
        "queryBuilder": {
            depends: "jQuery.extendext",
            exports: "jQuery"
        },
        "dataTables": {
            depends: "jQuery.extendext",
            exports: "jQuery.fn.dataTable"
        }
    }
});
```

```

The page in question has the following:

```

```
require(["knockout", "jquery", "./Page/rtfAreaEditing", "./Page/pager", "queryBuilder"], function (ko, $, rtfAreaEditing) {
                $(function() {
                    //Actual stuff being executed
                });
            });
```

```

About one time out of seven or thereabouts, a hard refresh of the page (or reloading it with no cache) will result in an error of

`$.fancybox is not a function`

I'm invoking it like:

   `$(someElement).fancybox();`

The rest of the time, it works perfectly. I know I must be doing something daft, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would just comment but I can't yet. Have you tried nesting a require call for fancy box. Sounds like your dealing with a race condition.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but it does seem like a race condition. What do you mean by nesting a require call for it?

Comment: require(["knockout", "jquery", "./Page/rtfAreaEditing", "./Page/pager", "queryBuilder"], function (ko, $, rtfAreaEditing) {
                $(function() {
                  add another require statment here for fancy
                });
            });

Comment: I tried checking $.fancybox to see if it was defined, then calling require("fancybox") if it wasn't. In some cases, it still doesn't load it. I also tried adding fancybox as a parameter to the function. Sometimes it's there and sometimes it isn't. It's like it periodically just doesn't retrieve it at all, but thinks it has.